# Using T-SQL how do you calculate a test grade percentage?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, integer-division

It what should be a simple task, or a simple google search, I have come up empty. I am trying to simply calculate a grade percentage. I am trying to use:

```
Select round((133 / 150), 2) * 100
```

That results in 0. I am trying to calcualte to get a score of 89%. I have tried multiple combinations and I am beginning to think it is either too complicated to do with t-sql or it is not possible. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select round((cast(133 as numeric(20,8))/ cast(150 as numeric(20,8))) * 100, 2)
```

You are using integers in your example, when you need decimal values.  See [here](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2008/11/4/Division-of-integers-in-MS-SQL) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Select round(133.0 / 150) * 100
```

An `int` divided by an `int` is an `int`, and 1 / 2 = 0 (integer truncation)

More generally, if you ensure numerator is a float (real/decimal):

```
Select round(CAST(integervalue as real) / 150) * 100
```